# Geometric Descriptions of Kernel and Range of T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a pretty straightforward question. First, I was given a linear transformation of T : R^2 to R^2. I found that the dimension of the kernel was 1 and the dimension of the range was 1. This is what the case should be because the dimensions should add to equal the dimension of R^2. I was told to give a geometric description of the kernel and range.

Now, my question is how do I go about turning the information into a geometric description? An explanation that applies to all problems that ask this would be preferable.

I believe that dim[ker(T)]=1 means that it is either a point or a line, but I'm not sure which and I've had trouble finding information on this.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Dimension $1$ is always going to be a line (it's a subspace with a basis consisting of a single vector). Have you tried actually *plotting* the kernel and image, to see what things look like?

Comment: A one dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ should be a line through the origin. Why? Because one dimensional implies there is only one basis element and the span of a single vector is a line. If there were only one point in your subspace that subspace must be $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Comment: If the dimension was zero then it would be a point, right? And then dimension 2 would be a plane, 3 a 3-space, and so on?

Comment: Yes, the only $0$-dimensional subspace of any vector space is the trivial subspace, $\{0\}$.

Comment: Note that even though $\ker T$ and $\operatorname{im} T$ are (in this case) lines through the origin, they need not be distinct.